# How to remove continuslly pipe with two pipe character in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove continually pipe with two pipe character in javascript.

```
var testString="||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||f_test!!3!!||f_test!!4!!||f_test!!5!!||";

output ="||f_test!!3!!||f_test!!4!!||f_test!!5!!||";
```

I was try below

```
replace("||||||f_", "||f_")//but no limit for pipe
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSXb6/785/)**

**Important :In testString not any limit for pipe it's must be 20,40,50,60, or etc.**

but output should be same.

But I only want 2 pipe before f_

How can do this using JavaScript.

Comment: Please show what you tried that didn't work. This isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use positive lookahead for the regular expression

```
/\|(?=\|\|)/g
```

and replace only a pipe if it is followed by two more pipes.

```js
var testString="||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||f_test!!3!!||f_test!!4!!||f_test!!5!!||";

console.log(testString.replace(/\|(?=\|\|)/g, ''));
```